# Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::hasGetMutator does not exist

Tags: laravel

Laravel z-song Admin
after the composer update, this error appeared and not one type of grid wants to render

Comment: [SO generally works in English](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/); Please make sure your post is as useful as possible to others by translating it

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `artisan view:clear` and if it doesn't work then remove `$grid->showTools()`

or  change `$grid->build('Build');` to  `$grid->column('build');`

good luck